# How to fix error DataError: No numeric types to aggregate

Tags: python, pandas-groupby, aggregate-functions, median

I need to Group by addr_state column. and apply aggregate function median on annual_inc column. My code:

ax = loan_df.groupby('addr_state')['annual_inc'].aggregate(['median']).plot.bar()

But I am getting the error: DataError: No numeric types to aggregate

Comment: Could you edit your post to include part of your data frame? e.g. the output of `loan_df.head()`

Answer (score 0):

- you have not provided sample data.  Have simulated what I can imply
- this is down to data in your data frame.  Simulated below some bad data on second attempt to create plot

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

loan_df = pd.DataFrame({"addr_state":np.repeat(list("ABCDE"),10), "annual_inc":np.random.randint(30,50,50)})
ax = loan_df.groupby('addr_state')['annual_inc'].aggregate(['median']).plot.bar()

# make random values in data none numeric
loan_df.loc[loan_df.sample(3).index, "annual_inc"] = "#n/a"
try:
    ax = loan_df.groupby('addr_state')['annual_inc'].aggregate(['median']).plot.bar()
except TypeError:
    print("bad data...")
```